# Automate refresh Power BI after SAP BW loads

Tags: powerbi, load, hana, sap-bw

Currently all business users schedule Power BI reports around 08:00 / 09:00 AM. 2 Problems... overload and the possibility that our SAP BW loads didn't finish yet.

I need some ideas how to automate the refresh of Power BI reports after our daily SAP BW load is finished (Using SAP BW/4HANA).

We have a HANA View with the timestamp on which the load is finished, which can be consumed in Power BI.

Thoughts so far:

- Power Automate by Power BI?
- Approach a Python script with an ABAP scripts

If someone has experience with this or has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

Kinds regards,

Justin

Comment: You can achieve this with a fair amount of work.  I created a trigger at the process chain level (via a custom Process Type) which would send an event to a listening service so it knows something is finished/ready to be extracted.  It's not loads of work but it needs thought.  We devised that for our data lake implementation for all of the data that is sent from BW to the lake for processing.  It's all event driven rather than having to line up schedules that run the risk of not lining up.

Comment: I could consult for you guys if need be, unlikely you'd want me to but ... the offer is there.  :-)